# Load syntax highlighting when neovim starts

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, shada

I got:

```
set shada=!,'100,<50,s10,h,f1,s100,%
```

Which make Vim reload last buffers when I exit (or :wshada was called ) .

However, the buffers are loaded without syntax and highlighting. I need to reload each buffer, and `:bufdo :e` didn't work.

I wish to somehow reload all buffers on start.

Comment: Are the filetype of the loaded buffers correctly detected?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What problem are you trying to solve? Isn't Syntax highlighting activated as soon as you actually jump to one of those buffers?

Comment: No, it doesn't, @ChristianBrabandt. No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution based on @vivian

```
function! OnWinEnter()
    if !&filetype
        filetype detect
    endif
endfunction
autocmd BufWinEnter * call OnWinEnter()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you:

```
:windo filetype detect
```

Comment: that should be `bufdo`? shouldn't it?

Comment: I have in my `vimrc`: `autocmd SessionLoadPost * windo filetype detect` and it works at detecting the first split file type but not the other split file type :-|. With `autocmd SessionLoadPost * bufdo filetype detect` it does not work. Unless I run it manually when the GUI is loaded. I never manage to find an event to make it working perfectly.

Comment: I realize that I have that odd behavior only when [Startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) is active. I don't know if that is also the problem of @eyal.

Comment: Good direction at least. I thought it works, it does solve folding (bufdo), but not highlighting. windo works on the current displayed window. I think maybe on bufferenter, but it might not be great in terms of performance. I think it only reload highlighting if it is currently displayed.

Comment: Do you confirm that you are also using [Startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify)?

Comment: I don't have it.

Comment: Since you are using `shada` I suppose your are using Neovim. Could you confirm? Could you tell us which version of Neovim you are using?

Comment: I do. I use neovim 0.8.1